# GRPC create channel link for Google Assistant API

Tags: c++, google-assistant-sdk

I'm trying to write a C++ code to create Google Assistant on UDOO x86 board (See https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/).
I have tried to follow all the steps regarding in the tutorial, but I'm not sure what URL I should have when I call the creatChannel method?

I do have the credentials JSON downloaded and using it through the "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS" environment variable

Object creation:

```
GAssistantClient greeter(grpc::CreateChannel(
      "google.com", grpc::GoogleDefaultCredentials()));
```

Contructor:

```
GAssistantClient(std::shared_ptr<Channel> channel)
      : stub_(Greeter::NewStub(channel)) {}
```

When I put google.com in there, I get the following error:
E0505 18:30:34.959710444    7635 ssl_transport_security.c:1226] Invalid toplevel subdomain: com
E0505 18:30:34.959836517    7635 ssl_transport_security.c:1226] Invalid toplevel subdomain: com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Service name for the Google Assistant API is **embeddedassistant.googleapis.com**. So your object creation call would look like:

```
GAssistantClient greeter(grpc::CreateChannel(
      "embeddedassistant.googleapis.com", grpc::GoogleDefaultCredentials()));
```

Comment: Thank you $Prisoner

Comment: Now there is no error but, the I don't get any reply from the Google API [I see the request on my dashboard in the Google API interface]. I do set all the config's along with the request.

Comment: I suggest you ask this as a separate question that provides the code samples for how you're making the request and waiting for the reply.

Answer (score 2):

You have to authenticate using your credentials and then create a channel, after that you have send audio config request about your audio and then send an audio data request which contains your audio captured etc.

You can use ALSA sound API library to capture and playback audio.
and then send and receive in api requests and responses.

You should follow the [following order in this doc](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/reference/rpc/google.assistant.embedded.v1alpha1)